# amateras html editor not opening files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse STS IDE. Using [Amateras HTML editor plugin](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor). I was working fine but after restart, I am not able to restart any files using this editor. I see this error in eclipse log file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jface/action/MenuManager;Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelectionProvider;Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;)V
                at tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor.editors.SplitPageHTMLEditor$SplitEditorSite.registerContextMenu(SplitPageHTMLEditor.java:234)
                at tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor.editors.SplitPageHTMLEditor$SplitEditorSite.registerContextMenu(SplitPageHTMLEditor.java:282)
                at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3521)
                at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:54)
                at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:447)
                at tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor.editors.HTMLSourceEditor.createPartControl(HTMLSourceEditor.java:162)
                at tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor.editors.SplitPageHTMLEditor.createPartControl(SplitPageHTMLEditor.java:131)
                at tk.eclipse.plugin.htmleditor.editors.HTMLEditor.createPartControl(HTMLEditor.java:128)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
                at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
                ... 95 more
```

I restarted eclipse multiple times but still not working. Whats wrong? Is there any cache to clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new workspace and it works fine.